# Laravel: Eloquent Querybuilder whereTimestamp?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, timestamp

I have a query I am trying to build with the laravel eloquent query builder. I'm relatively new to Laravel and I'm looking for the method that will query against a date AND a time.

My use case: Fetch the child records for MyModel created in the last hour.

My query:

```
$childQuery = function($query) {
$timezone = new Timezone('UTC');
// whereDate only compares a Date value
// whereTime only compares the Time value
$query->whereDate('custom_timestamp' 
            ,'>='
            ,   Carbon::now($timezone)->addSeconds(-3600));
};
MyModel::with(['myChildModels' => $childQuery])->find($myModelId);
```

How do I perform a timestamp comparison?
I'm sure I am just missing something simple, but amazingly enough I couldn't find a single reference in the docs to comparing timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the data type of the `custom_timestamp` field? Are you talking UNIX timestamp (integer) or e.g. MySQL timestamp (string '2019-06-04 23:40:07')?

If `custom_timestamp` is an integer data type, then your query would be

```php
$childQuery = function($query) {
    $query->where('custom_timestamp','>=', time()-3600); // time() is always UTC
};
MyModel::with(['myChildModels' => $childQuery])->find($myModelId);
```

If `custom_timestamp` is a datetime data type, say a MySQL timestamp, your query would be something like

```php
$childQuery = function($query) {
    $query->where('custom_timestamp','>=', now('UTC')->subHour());
};
MyModel::with(['myChildModels' => $childQuery])->find($myModelId);
```

This is MySQL syntax – your DB syntax may vary. The main thing is that you don't *need* to use Eloquent's date helper methods to work with dates. It's generally easier not to.

Also notice the global `now()` helper, and that you can pass 'UTC' directly as a string. One of the benefits of Laravel leveraging Carbon.

Comment: Yes - subHour is what I was looking for, I must say it's not named intuitively which is unusual for laraval from what I have seen thus far. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now, but I would have thought you just want your custom timestamp to be greater than one hour ago.

```
->whereDate('custom_timestamp', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHour())
```